# Can you vent a portable AC's exhaust through the chimney?

Tags: air-conditioning

The place I live doesn't have sliding windows so I thought maybe I could vent the hot air from the portable AC through the chimney? The chimney belongs to the fireplace that I don't use. (I've not bought the AC yet.)

Comment: is the flue in question used for any other purpose such as a heater, furnace, etc?  Shared use is a very bad idea and potentially dangerous.

Comment: What kind of portable? That is, what's the output -- a flexible ductwork? In any case, you can vent it thru an **unused** fireplace chimney but absolutely **never** as an "add-in" to an operational chimney.

Comment: Portable ACs that vent only hot air are very uneconomical in the first place (they waste most of the cool air they produce on cooling themselves). You should look for portable-split AC, so you can route the freon cables through a relatively small hole. Gives much better results with lower energy consumption.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it works, I've done it.

It's much more efficient and effective to vent the hot air out a chimney - this is what the chimney was designed for - than to open a window for the outlet. Opening a window as per the usual instructions creates an uninsulated opening to the hot outdoors, leading to heat entering your house even as you try to cool it.

So long as the chimney is sound, and penetrates through the roof (some old chimneys may be sealed off if no longer in use), it's a good option. Try to jam the vent pipe up as far as you can to make sure the hot air goes up.

Comment: It works the best if you can seal the hot air exhaust in the flue. I have done this in the past using a piece of Ridgid insulation that fit snugly into the opening. You will need some makeup air for the air that is exhausted or the system will not be able to cool properly.

Comment: I have as well, used rigid foam to seal everything off and then cut a hole for the exhaust hose to go through.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but ONLY if it's a less efficient single vent exhaust unit. If the unit has two hoses, one is for cool air intake (to cool the coils) and the other is to exhaust the hot waste air. A single hose unit is less efficient because it takes the cooler inside air to cool the coils, meaning you're wasting energy taking the previously cooled air to cool the coils. If you have a dual hose unit, I would suggest installing a vent to the outside to bring in cool air (like dryer rigid tubing). Put a mesh over it to keep bugs and critters out.

The other catch here is if the chimney is dirty. You could knock loose debris off, which could get sucked up in your AC. I would have it cleaned before using it as exhaust.

Answer (score 0):

If it is truly a traditional fireplace chimney and your AC unit has a flexible exhaust hose you could use the fireplace. Like mentioned above, make sure you are the only one who uses the fireplace. Sometimes water heaters and furnaces in older homes will be vented through the chimney. I would think using a piece of wire you could secure the flexible vent hose to the flu vent up inside the so the warm air could go right up the chimney.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread I came across while researching portable ACs. For what it's worth, I have vented my portable AC through the cooking stove hood exhaust in my apartment building (made an adapter plate which I then replaced the filter with). It worked with the hood smoke extractor on. But the setup suffered from the well-known issue of single-exhaust portable ACs -- the negative pressure. I only managed to cool by about 5C (10F), but it was better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

They will actually heat the room. Cool air feels good coming out but. The refrigeration removes so many BTUs and exhausts them as heat. Now to do this a compressor is used that burns watts of power, that is also converted to heat, (called heat of compression) it is part of the exhaust, think where that might go? If the outside air is cooler than the inside an exhaust fan may be the best choice. I would suggest getting an AC that has a isolated input output section then you will not be cooling your heated air.